# How to find $\lim_{n\to\infty}n\cdot\sin(2\pi\ e\ n!)$?

Tags: calculus, limits

What will be the value of this limit?

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}n\cdot\sin(2\pi\ e\ n!)$$

Any help on how to proceed?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Consider that, as $n$ increases, the distance of $e n!$ from the closest integer drops to zero, since:
$$ n!e=n!\cdot\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{k!}=A+\frac{1}{(n+1)}+\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)}+\ldots $$
where $A\in\mathbb{N}$. This gives:
$$ \{n! e\} = \frac{1}{n+1}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$
and:
$$n\sin(2\pi n! e) = n\sin\left(2\pi\left(\frac{1}{n+1}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)\right)\right),$$
so the limit is $2\pi$.

Comment: Did you expand $\sin (a+b)$ in the last step?

Comment: I just used $\sin(2\pi(A+u))=\sin(2\pi A+2\pi u)=\sin(2\pi u)$ that comes from $A\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: I'm sorry, what's A here? $\frac{1}{n+1}$?

Comment: @Alex: $$A = n!\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{1}{k!}\in\mathbb{N}.$$

Comment: @JackDAurizio Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think since $n$ tends to infinity, $\sin(2\pi e n!)$ will oscillate between $1$ and $-1$ whereas $n$ will tend to infinity so that the limit also tends to infinity. Thanks!

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: I'm sorry, my question is how you got the limit from $\sin(2 \pi (\frac{1}{n+1} + O(\cdot))$? Did you use the $\sin (a + b)  = \sin a \cos b  + \cos a \sin b$ expansion?

Comment: For both of you: we have $\sin(2\pi(A+u))=\sin(2\pi u)$, where $u$ is very small. Since $$\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{\sin z}{z}=1,$$ the claim follows.

Answer (score 4):

Expand $e=1+\frac11+\frac1{2!}+...+\frac1{n!}+...$

Comment: And so? We have to bound pretty well the distance of $n!e$ from the closest integer.

Comment: Yes, the first $n+1$ terms up to $1/n!$ become integers, then you get $1/(n+1)+1/(n+1)(n+2)+...$