# limit of a sequence with $\pi $ and $ e $

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Let $$ a_n = \frac{n}{\pi}sin(2\pi e n!)  $$ Find $$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n $$ I tried expanding using the Taylor series representation of $e$ but I arrived nowhere.

Comment: [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1054377/how-to-find-lim-n-to-inftyn-cdot-sin2-pi-e-n) may help.

Comment: That definitely helped David. I have my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've chosen the right method, it should be conclusive.

$e = \sum_{k=0}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{k!} $

$\implies 2\pi n! e = 2\pi*K + \frac{2\pi}{n+1} + o(\frac{1}{n})$, K being a positive integer (why is that?)

$\sin(2\pi n! e)= sin(\frac{2\pi}{n+1} + o(\frac{1}{n})) = \frac{2\pi}{n+1} + o(\frac{1}{n}) $

$\implies a_n = \frac{2n}{n+1} + o(1) $

Hence (if I'm not mistaken): $(a_n) \rightarrow 2$ , when $ n \rightarrow +\infty$

Comment: For some reasons that elude me I have a crave for getting accepted answers on duplicates, I feel very useful...

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $$\frac1{n+1}+n!\sum_{k=0}^n\frac1{k!}\lt n!\mathrm e\lt\frac1n+n!\sum_{k=0}^n\frac1{k!}$$