# How to compute $\lim_{n\to \infty} n\sin(2\pi n! e)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I want to calculate

> $$\lim_{n\to \infty} n\sin(2\pi n! e)$$

I have used the Stirling approximation and I think the answer is zero . But I think the limit maybe not exists.

Can some one help?  Thanks.

Comment: why do you think the limit is zero?

Comment: Check this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1057350/limit-of-a-sequence-with-pi-and-e/1057359#1057359

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\sin(2\pi e n!)=\sin(2\pi n!(1+1+1/2!+\ldots+1/n!+\ldots))=\sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{n+1}\right)+o(n^{-1}),$$ so the limit equals $2\pi$.